# Confirm in Confirm

Tags: javascript, html

What am I doing wrong? I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myRemove is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):20)

```
<script> 
function myRemove() {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account?");
} else {
    // do nothing
    if (r == true) {
        document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
        var r = confirm("Your account has been removed/deleted. Keep in mind, you must have an active account to use our internet services. Do you want to register again?");
        if (r == true) {
            window.location.href = "http://EXAMPLE.COM";
        }
    } else {
        alert("Alright, you decided to stay on this page and to not re-register.");
    }
```

Here is the button's code:

```
<a value="Remove account" onclick="myRemove()" on class="btn">Remove Your Account</a>
```

Comment: You're missing a whole lot of opening/closing tags, that's probably why the compiler can't properly define the end of the function, causing the error

Comment: I edited the post, can you take look?

Comment: Indent your code correctly, and you'll see all the brackets that are missing/double/etc in an instant

Comment: You can solve a lot of these bugs faster by `pr  op erly for          matting yourcode`

Comment: Reformatted... Check the post.

Comment: As you can see now, you start with an `} else {` which is not possible, it needs an `if (...) {` before that.. and the end `}` of that if-clause is missing. And the closing `}` of the function is also missing... come on put some effort in your work

Comment: **sidenote:** You can put the `confirm` directly in the if-clause, saving a line for every confirm: `if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account?")) {...}` (Many tutorials, w3schools for one, teach it with the variable, but it really adds no benefit if you're only checking the confirm once anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts has syntax errors, so myRemove is not defined.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<script>
function myRemove() {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account?");
    if (r == true) {
        document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
        var r = confirm("Your account has been removed/deleted. Keep in mind, you must have an active account to use our internet services. Do you want to register again?");
        if (r == true) {
           window.location.href = "http://EXAMPLE.COM";
        } else {
           // do nothing
        }
    } else {
       alert("Alright, you decided to stay on this page and to not re-register.");
    }
}
</script>
```